# Switch between GPS_PROVIDER and NET PROVIDER when device is stationary for a period of time in Android

Tags: android, gps

I'm writing a GPS Tracker which I use for getting the location of the device every minute. I use both  `GPS_PROVIDER` and `NET_PROVIDER` to get the location, but sometimes, the location is not getting updated even though I'm moving the device for a long time.

So I'm thinking:

> If the location is not changing for a period of time with a certain provider, switch to another provider and check for new location again.

Is this correct?

Here's my getLocation code:

```
public Location getLocation(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
                this.canGetLocation = false;
                Log.d("DMCAILOCATION","DMCAILOCATION: can not get location");
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                //=======================
                Location location=null;
                Location locationGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Location locationNet = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                Log.d("DMCAILOCATION","DMCAILOCATION: locationGPS:"+locationGPS + "locationNet:"+ locationNet  );
                if ( locationGPS != null ) {
                    location= locationGPS;
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    getLocationnet();
                    Log.d("DMCAILOCATION","DMCAILOCATION: get by gps");
                }
                else  {
                    location= locationNet;              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    getLocationgps();   
                    Log.d("DMCAILOCATION","DMCAILOCATION: get by net");
                }
                Log.i("DMCAILOCATION","NetLocationTime:" + locationNet.getTime() + "locationGPS.getTime(): " +locationGPS.getTime());


                Log.d("DMCAILOCATION","DMCAILOCATION: LAT: "+latitude+", "+longitude);              
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

Comment: I'm no expert in android, but I think this is a good idea. Have you tried doing this already? If so what are your results?

Comment: I'm still can not resolver it :D